# access Enum Items Inside Index View

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, enums

i am trying to get enum items value inside Index View to Create drop down list for the items of Enum....but i couldn't....how to get enum items value?

the enum:
    public enum ReportType

```
 {
        [Display(Name = "None")]
        None = 0,
        [Display(Name = "NotRelated")]
        NotRelated = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Violation")]
        Violation = 2,
        [Display(Name = "HateSpeech")]
        HateSpeech = 3

    };
```

the drop down list in View:

```
 <select>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @if (item.ReportType.ToString()!=1) {
                  <option value="0">@item.EventNameAr</option>
                }
        }
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use :

```
 @if ((int)item.ReportType != 1) {
      <option value="0">@item.EventNameAr</option>
 }
```

But you can use display name instead :

```
 @if (item.ReportType.ToString() != "NotRelated") {
      <option value="0">@item.EventNameAr</option>
 }
```